# Why is it called Epsilon for DBSCAN?

Tags: clustering, terminology, dbscan

The two parameters of DBSCAN are epsilon and minimum samples. Shouldn't epsilon be called like "Circle radius"? Why is it called epsilon?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to have a *reason* to name a parameter. They could have called it "r", too.

The intuition probably is that `epsilon` will usually be a rather small value - much smaller than the data set diameter or average distance. It's not just *some* arbitrary radius, but a small non-empty radius.

Probably the naming was just inherited from earlier work; likely in data indexing.

Data indexes to accelerate radius queries can work in $O(\log n)$ - but only if the query is selective, i.e. only selects a small part of the data set. If the result is of size $O(n)$, no index will help enumerating the result (nor will DBSCAN yield interesting clusters). I've seen the range queries been called "epsilon range queries" for that reason - they should be used with a small radius to be fast.

But they could have named it $\chi$, $\xi$, $\zeta$, $\Upsilon$, $\Xi$, $\ddagger$, $\heartsuit$, $\Im$, $\hbar$, $\mho$ if they were in the mood to fool around ...

Comment: Note that in the mathematical subject of real analysis, it is very common to refer to "neighbourhoods" or "balls" of radius epsilon around some point, in the exact same sense as in the DBSCAN context. This convention is very heavily used in textbooks and classes.